# different methods for rar archives

Tags: file-compression

When I pack my data to .rar archive, I usually make backup original data. But last time I forgot about backup, and when I opened .rar file, I got - Invalid or corrupt authenticity information. Someone, please advise how to repair winrar files or even one file.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like **[howtos](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185),** [manuals/tutorials](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your question accordingly, and it can be reopened.